# Como transformar um numero com virgula no R?

Tags: r

Tenho um arquivo csv, salvo via Excel (usando o ";" como separador de colunas). Quando o importo para o R os números que estão no formato 0,00 ficam como fator e com a virgula.

Ex: "123,45"

Ao fazer a conversão ele fica como texto.

```
num <- gsub("," , "." , "123,45")
```

num = "123.45"

quando eu os converto individualmente eles viram número.

```
num <- as.numeric(num)
```

num = 123.45

Mas quando faço isso num vetor , os números ficam arredondados.

```
numeros <- gsub(",",".",numeros)
numeros <- as.numeric(numeros)
```

numeros = 123 457 ...

Mesmo usando um loop a mesma coisa acontece.

```
for (i in 1:lenght(numeros)) {
    numeros[i] <- as.numeric(numeros[i]
}
```

numeros = 123 457 ...

Gostaria de saber como números com virgula em números no padrão do R.

Answer (score 6):

Quando for ler o dados do arquivo csv, utilize o argumento `dec` para especificar o separador do decimal:

```
read.csv('dados.csv', dec = ",")
```

Answer (score 6):

Creio que o que pretende deve ser resolvido com `sub` e não com `gsub`.

```
x <- c("123,45", "456,78", "0,001")
y <- sub(",", ".", x)
y
[1] "123.45" "456.78" "0.001"

as.numeric(y)
[1] 123.450 456.780   0.001
```

Note que como `0.001` tem três casas decimais, o método `print.numeric` é suficientemente esperto para também dar os outros elementos do vetor com 3 decimais.

Em relação à sugestão do @Willian Vieira de usar o argumento `dec = ","` no momento da leitura do ficheiro, é claro que isso é o desejável, mas o R tem a função `read.csv2` precisamente para ler ficheiros `.csv`  que vêm de países onde as decimais são separadas com a vírgula.
Na página `help("read.table")` (ou `read.csv`, é a mesma página) pode-se ler o seguinte. Ênfase minha.

> read.csv and read.csv2 are identical to read.table except for the
> defaults.   They are intended for reading ‘comma separated value’
> files (‘.csv’) or   (read.csv2) the variant used in **countries that use
> a comma as decimal point   and a semicolon as field separator**.

Em, Português, tradução Google editada por mim.

> `read.csv` e `read.csv2` são idênticos a `read.table`, exceto nos padrões. Destinam-se à leitura de arquivos de ‘valores separados por vírgula’ (‘.csv’) ou (read.csv2) a variante usada em **países que usam uma vírgula como ponto decimal e um ponto e vírgula como separador de campo.**

Parece ser este o caso descrito na pergunta.